# Struts2 Date tag display weekdays like Wed, 13 Feb, 2013 9:00 AM

Tags: java, struts2

How can we use the struts2 date tag to display the below format

Wed, 13 Feb, 2013 9:00 AM

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i know you already got your answer, yes it is

```
<date name="customDate" format="EEE, d MMM, yyyy h:mm a" />
```

Struts 2 also uses **java.text.SimpleDateFormat** for date format, you might what to look it up to understand more about it. hope it helps in-case you want to make use of another special format in any future. cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Make use of format attribute of data tag

```
<date name="customDate" format="EEE, d MMM, yyyy h:mm a" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this format `EEE, dd MMM, yyyy HH:mm aaa`-

```
<s:date name="customDate" format="EEE, dd MMM, yyyy HH:mm aaa" />
```

Answer (score 0):

use this tag: `<s:date />`,
just like this:

```
<s:date name="#date" format="EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss aaa" />
```

Comment: thanks for your answer,before that i'm really struggling to display weekdays. Now it is working again many thanks.